# classic asp encryption for text

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, asp-classic

My question is about encrypting data in classic ASP and what the best course of action would be to encrypt text (not passwords) for storage and then allow all users to have access to the data (decrypt it). Basically the project consists of a classic ASP application that allows users to create accounts and see messages from other users. These messages need to be encrypted before being stored. 
I have found some classic ASP encryption methods including Microsoft CAPICOM but the website points to a link where the download can be found for it and actually is a dead link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995332.aspx
I have also seen some other forums posts mention creating a .net web service that will handle the encryption/decryption process which can be called from the classic ASP files. 
I also stumbled on another concept which does not use the public/private key and uses an approach and uses a shared private key?

So I am hoping someone might know what method is best to try and accomplish this.

Comment: how is this related to VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You only had to Google [`CAPICOM download`](https://www.google.com/search?q=CAPICOM%20download).

> Site: [Download Center: Platform SDK Redistributable: CAPICOM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25281)
>
> This download contains the redistributable files for CAPICOM 2.1.0.2 and samples of its use. CAPICOM can be used to digitally sign data, sign code, verify digital signatures, envelop data for privacy, hash data, encrypt/decrypt data and more.
>
> ```
>  Version:          2.1.0.2        File Name:   capicom_dc_sdk.msi  
>  Date Published:   9/26/2016      File Size:   1.8 MB
> ```
>
> [image]

See also: [**Alternatives to Using CAPICOM**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc778518.aspx)

Comment: So using CAPICOM is the best course of action to follow to accomplish what I am asking? I only listed CAPICOM because it was something I found in my research.
Can you answer why this is the best solution to my question?
Also why was my question downgraded? I listed my research but am reaching out to the Stack Overflow community for advice on how to approach this, not where can I find CAPICOM. I just noted that the Microsoft webpage for CAPICOM had a dead link.